# Make webpack ignore a certain import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm trying to create a desktop app using [ElectronJS](https://electronjs.org/) and [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/).

The renderer process is bundled using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), since i'm using JSX in it.

When I try to import anything from electron (e.g. `import electron from 'electron';`, or `const electron = require('electron');`) in the renderer process I get these 2 errors when I either try to build it with webpack (the web part), or when I use webpack-dev-server and open the localhost URL in electron:

https://pastebin.com/WdkCcPzm

Note that I'm not using `create-react-app`, that `bundle.js` is webpack's output, `App.jsx` is the file I'm trying to import electron from, that I want to import electron to access the ipcRenderer variable and that I'm not attempting to import `fs` from the renderer process (or from the main process for that matter).

A solution I found was to bypass webpack's packing by adding this line to my `index.js`

```
eval('window.Electron = require("electron")');
```

and accessing electron though the variable `Electron` (the capital E is because vs code recognizes that as a namespace even though electron isn't imported, and thus I still get code completion)

But that's really ugly and I was hoping there was another solution.

Comment: take a look if this is your case: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3012

Comment: exactly, did you use *target: 'electron-main'* and *target: 'electron-renderer'* in your webpack config?

Comment: @PatrickHund, I am not buildnig the main process with webpack, I just have the main property in my `package.json` set to a file which requires `'babel-registry'`, and then my actual main file of the main process to be able to use es2015 modules.

Comment: OK, but are you building the renderer process with *target: 'electron-renderer'*? The link to the GitHub issue that @skyboyer posted seems to be the exact same issue, and that's the solution

Comment: Oh, didn't understand what you meant first, but thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build bundles for the renderer process of Electron apps, webpack provides a special target parameter.

Add this to your webpack config:

```
target: 'electron-renderer'
```

See documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/